# UILabel attributedText with multiple line break modes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a requirement of showing a UILabel with text that has two different styles (different colours, parts of the text bolded). This is solved easily enough by using the attributedText-property.

My problem is that the text may or may not be longer than what I can fit in my label. When using plain text everything works the way I want it to. The text is word wrapped to fit the number of lines in the label and the tail is truncated if/when the text is longer than can be shown in the label.

When I switch to using attributedText I am only able to choose between tail truncation and word wrapping. If I want the tail truncated the label only renders a single line with the truncated tail (even though it could fit 10 lines). If I choose word wrapping then the tail is not truncated but the lines that cannot fit in the label are simply not shown.

My content string does not contain any line breaks, it is simply one long string.

Comment: Have you considered firing a bug to Apple?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554815/294884 and also **pikachu**'s answer below here

Answer (score 14):

I missed truncation when I set linespacing, but all I had to to was add linebreakmode to paragraphstyle

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragrahStyle setLineSpacing:1.5];
[paragrahStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Long string that truncates"];
[attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrahStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedText length])];

self.label.attributedText = attributedText;
```

Answer (score 5):

They only way I've been able to get this to work is to not set a paragraph style.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

[_text drawWithRect:_textRect
                 options:**NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine**
              attributes:attributes
                 context:nil];

Comment: I think this is it.  also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554815/294884   it's unfortunate you can ONLY achieve this with an attributed string.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an `NSParagraphStyle` with any `lineBreakMode` you please, and apply it to the string using `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`. I don't know if all of the values of `NSLineBreakMode` are supported, but I have no reason to believe they aren't.

Comment: I did this and tried setting multiple styles on it but the second style was always ignored. This is what I tried: self.paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

Comment: These styles are not masks; you can't combine them like that.