# UILabel attributed text can't have multiple lines if you change baseline offset attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I want to change brackets's baseline offset in a words, like "[推]blablabla".

```
NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:@"[推]"];
if (range.location == 0) {
    [text addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@(0.5) range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    [text addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@(0.5) range:NSMakeRange(range.length-1, 1)];
}
```

but the second line of the label disappears and gets truncated. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I meet the same issue, looks like bug to me.

Answer (score 5):

Please use lineBreakMode and numberOfLines
Also to call sizeToFit, like this:

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[label sizeToFit];
```

The height will be automatically computed.

Thanks

Comment: I use autolayout, sizeToFit is useless. I already set lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail and numberOfLines = 2.

Answer (score 1):

I've did some quick test, and it seems that if you add a whitespace at the first of your string, it will work as expected

```
// make sure your text looks like @" [推]your content"
if (range.location == 1) {
    [text addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@(0.5) range:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
    [text addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@(0.5) range:NSMakeRange(range.length, 1)];
}
```

Comment: I test and it don't work. can you explain your code a little more.

Comment: @AlenLiang In my experiment, the setting of `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` on different characters will effect the truncation. Try different combination of range index will make it correct. Are you sure your text is like `@" [推]your content"`, especially have a space in the first?

Comment: Try different combination of range index will make it correct. sounds quite tricky for me, I don't use @" [推]your content", just add a whitespace at the beginning of my string. Still it looks like bug.

Comment: @AlenLiang Yeah. I think we can open a radar

Comment: I happen to test this bug, and now it works whatever your string is. in iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

If you using storyboard see the below image, select the Label, then see the Lines is set 0 and Line Breaks set Word Wrap thats solve.

[image]

or if you use code,

Objective C:

```
LabelName.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
LabelName.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Swift:

```
LabelName.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
LabelName.numberOfLines = 0
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `NSMutableParagraphStyle` to set lineBreakMode as attribute?

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragrahStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];

[attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrahStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedText length])];
```

like proposed here: [UILabel attributedText with multiple line break modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831207/uilabel-attributedtext-with-multiple-line-break-modes)